# Android : Is Google Tag Manager connected to Firebase directly or through google analytics ? and how this cycle works

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Firebase -> Project Settings -> integrations, I found only Google Analytics, and cannot found Google Tag Manager, so I need to make sure that is my app is connected successfully to google tag manager.

Comment: Just to make sure, "throw" is a typo for "through", is it?

Comment: Yes , and it's fixed .

Answer (score 0):

Installation of GTM for Apps is documented here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5 (for iOS, but you should find Android instructions from there).

However if all you need is Google Analytics, Firebase is enough - you can then use the Google Analytics Integration (configured in your Firebase account) to analyze your data in a GA4 property.

Universal Analytics is no longer supported for Apps (was never supported in Firebase, and the Google Analytics SDKs for apps have been deprecated quite some time ago).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I need to connect at first to google tag manager, and I think to test the successful integration by analytics, cause it can be connected to the app throw tag manager.